# Scrapy Image Returns None

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the code from this image

```
<img alt="Prata Bom Cheese" class="realImage___2TyNE" src="https://d1sag4ddilekf6.cloudfront.net/compressed/items/SGITE20200430045730017104/photo/menueditor_item_922ff3e4ed464a32a1a0e5f02f4c383d_1589715446971551288.jpg" style="opacity: 1;">
```

with my code

```
imgURL = res.css('img').xpath('@src').extract_first()
n = res.css('img').xpath('@alt').get() 
yield ImagespiderItem(name = n, file_urls = [imgURL])
```

but for some reason scrapy only won't extract the `src`. It will still extract the `alt` and the other attributes. I've tried everything and I'm stuck here. Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you give a source webpage URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
response.css('.realImage___2TyNE ::attr(src)').get()
```